# Approximation of harmonic sum as a multiple of $\ln n$

Tags: calculus, analysis, logarithms, approximation

It is well-known that the harmonic series $\sum _{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{1+i}$ could be approximated to the natural logarithm $\ln$. Now, let $c$ be an arbitrary positive real number. Could one deduce that for a big enough $n$ the sum $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{i+e}$ is approximated as (or is less than) $\frac{1}{2c}\ln n$? Here, $e$ is the Euler base of natural logarithm.\ Thanks for any help!

Comment: Do you mean for *some* constant $c>0$, or an arbitrary one? One can make that formal, but even with the "+e" instead of "+1" you will get the same asymptotics $\ln n$.

Comment: @Ckement C. The number $c$ is supposed to be an arbitrary positive number as I edited the statement of the problem.

Comment: Well, since it'll be $\ln n + \Theta(1)$, the upper bound will only hold for $c\leq 1/2$.

Comment: For any $\alpha>0$, $$
\sum\limits_{i = 0}^{n - 1} {\frac{1}{{i + \alpha }}}  = \int_0^{n - 1} {\frac{{dt}}{{t + \alpha }}}  + \mathcal{O}(1) = \log (n + \alpha  - 1) - 1 + \mathcal{O}(1) = \log n + \mathcal{O}(1).
$$

Comment: @Gary typo: $-\log\alpha+O(1)$ instead of $-1+O(1)$

Comment: @GregMartin Indeed, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{i=0}^{i=n}\frac{1}{1+c\:i}=\frac{1}{c}\left(\psi(n+1+\frac{1}{c})-\psi(\frac{1}{c})\right)\qquad n>0$$

$\psi(x)$ is the digamma function. https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DigammaFunction.html

Asymptotic series :

$$\psi(z+1)\sim \ln(z)+\frac{1}{2z}-\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{B_{2k}}{2k\:z^{2k}}$$
$B_{2k}$ are the Bernoulli numbers : https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BernoulliNumber.html

Approximate at large $n$:
$$\psi(z+1)\sim \ln(z)+\frac{1}{2z}+...\quad\implies\quad \psi(n+1+\frac{1}{c})\sim \ln(n+\frac{1}{c})+\frac{1}{2(n+\frac{1}{c})}+...$$
$$\psi(n+1+\frac{1}{c})\sim \ln(n)+(\frac{2-c}{2c})\frac{1}{n}+...$$

$$\sum_{i=0}^{i=n\to\infty}\frac{1}{1+c\:i}\sim \frac{1}{c}\left(\ln(n)-\psi(\frac{1}{c})+(\frac{2-c}{2c})\frac{1}{n}\right)+...$$

$$\sum_{i=0}^{i=n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\alpha+i}\sim \ln(n)-\psi(\alpha)+(\alpha-\frac{1}{2})\frac{1}{n}+...$$

Comment: You can also use the following more general asymptotic expansion in terms of Bernoulli polynomials: $$
\psi (z + a) \sim \log z + \left( {a - \frac{1}{2}} \right)\frac{1}{z} - \sum\limits_{k = 2}^\infty  {\frac{{( - 1)^k B_k (a)}}{k}\frac{1}{{z^k }}} 
$$ for fixed $a \in \mathbb{C}$ and $|\arg z|<\pi$, $|z|\to +\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

Let $S(n)=-\ln n+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}1/(e+i).$ Then $$S(n+1)-S(n)=1/(e+n)-\ln (1+1/n)=B(n)-C(n)$$ where $B(n)=1/n-\ln (1+1/n)=1/2n^2-1/3n^3+...$

and $C(n)=1/n-1/(e+n)=e/(n^2+ne).$

Observe that $$S(n+1)=S(1)+\sum_{j=1}^{n+1} S(j+1)-S(j)=S(1)+\sum_{j=1}^{n+1}B(j)+C(j).$$ Observe that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{n+1}B(j)$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{n+1}C(j)$ both exist in $\Bbb R$ because $0<B(n)<1/2n^2$ and $0<C(n)<e/n^2$.

Comment: Thanks to both DanielWainfleet and J.Jaquelin for their answers. Now, how could we make $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{i+e}$ less than $\frac{1}{2c}\ln n$? Thanks again !

Comment: @karparvar The sum you just wrote in your comment is divergent. Are you sure you are summing up to $\infty$? Otherwise, are you happy with $$
\sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n - 1} {\frac{1}{{i + e}}}  = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n - 1} {\int_{i - 1}^i {\frac{{dt}}{{i + e}}} } \leq \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n - 1} {\int_{i - 1}^i {\frac{{dt}}{{t + e}}} }  = \int_0^{n - 1} {\frac{{dt}}{{t + e}}}  = \log (n + e - 1) - 1 \leq \log n?
$$

Comment: $S(n)$ converges to a limit $L$ as $n\to\infty.$ So for all sufficiently large $n$ we have  $L+1+\log n>\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}1/(e+i)>L-1+\log n.$ Now  if $c>1/2$ then $L-1+\log n >(\log n)/2c$ for all large $n.$ And if $c<1/2$ then $L+1+\log n <(\log n)/2c$ for all large $n$

Comment: @Gary Sorry! You are right and I should write the sum in the comment up to $n-1$. And I would be happy when the sum would become less than $1/2c \log n$ anyhow when $c$ is especially greater than $1/2$.

Comment: @karparvar Because of the asymptotics $\sim \log n$ any $c$ greater than $1/2$ will eventually not work. $c=1/2$ is the optimal constant and it works for all $n\geq 1$ as I showed.